# Using jfreechart, how would I change the color and style of the series

Tags: java, graphics, jfreechart

I'm a beginner programmer. This is my project for school. A lot the jfreechart implementation code is not my specific code, but it was taken other tutorials.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Resource class 
*/
public class Interest {
/**
 * Instance variables
 */
private double interestRate; //The rate of interest earned
private int time; //How many of one unit of time measurement -- generally, this is in terms of years
private int rate; //How many times during one unit of time will the interest compound 
private double investment; //The amount of money that's being invested
private final double inflation = .025; //The rate of which nominal value of increases by


/**
 * Default constructor
 * Default values
 */
public Interest() 
{
    time = 6;
    rate = 1;
    investment = 2000.00;
    interestRate = 2;
}

/**
 * 4-argument constructor
 * @param i
 * @param ir
 * @param t
 * @param r
 */
public Interest(double i, double ir, int t, int r)
{
    investment = i;
    time = t;
    rate =r;
    interestRate = ir;
}

/**
 * Class methods
 * @param time
 */

public void setTime(int time) //Sets the time instance variable in the resource class
{
    this.time = time;
}

public void setRate(int rate) //Sets the rate instance variable in the resource class
{
    this.rate = rate;
}

public void setInterestRate(double interestRate) //Sets the interest rate instance variable in the resource class
{
    this.interestRate = interestRate;
}

public void setInvestment(double investment) //Sets the investment instance variable in the resource class
{
    this.investment = investment;
}

public int getTime() //Gets the time instance variable in the resource class
{
    return time;
}

public double getInvestment() //Gets the investment instance variable in the resource class
{
    return investment;  
}

public int getRate() //Gets the rate instance variable in the resource class
{
    return rate;
}

public double getInterestRate() //Gets the interest rate instance variable in the resource class
{
    return interestRate;
}

public double cumulativeInvestmentValue() //Calculates the value of your investment over a certain period of time
{
    double decimalInterest = (double)(interestRate/100.00);
    return investment * (Math.pow(((decimalInterest/rate) + 1), (time * rate)));

}
public String getEquation() //Returns the equation of the function
{
    return "" + investment + "(1 + " + interestRate/100 + "/" + rate + ")^(x * " + rate + ")";
}

public double getDerivative(double x) //Calculates the slope of the tangent line at any given point
{
    int t = time;
    double r = rate;
    double i = investment;
    double ir = interestRate;
    double decimalInterestRate = ir/100;

    return  i * (r * (Math.pow((1 + decimalInterestRate/r), x * r)) * ((Math.log(1 + (decimalInterestRate/r))))); //This is the formula to find the derivative of any exponential function
}


public void cumulativeProgressiveInterestValue() //Prints a table of your investment, showing the value of it over time
{

    int iteration = 0;
    double realSum = investment;
    int t = time;
    int r = rate;
    double i = investment;
    double ir = interestRate;
    double decimalInterestRate = ir/100;

    Interest temp = new Interest(i, ir, t, r);

    ArrayList<Integer> time = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Double> derivative = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> nominalInterestSum = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> realInterestSum = new ArrayList<Double>();


    for(int x = 0; x <= t; x++)
    {
        time.add(iteration);
        iteration++;
        derivative.add(temp.getDerivative(x));
        nominalInterestSum.add(i * (Math.pow(((decimalInterestRate/r) + 1), (x * r))));
        realInterestSum.add((((Math.pow(((decimalInterestRate/r) + 1), (x * r)))/((Math.pow(((inflation) + 1), (x))))) * i));
        //realInterestSum.add(i * (Math.pow((((decimalInterestRate - inflation)/r) + 1), (x * r))));
    }

    System.out.println("InterestRate: " + ir + "\nRate: " + r + "\nInvestment: " + i + "\nTime: " + t);
    System.out.format("%-15s%-20s%-28s%-29s\n", "Time", "d/dx(Slope)", "Nominal sum accumulation", " Real sum accumulation");

    for(int x = 0; x <= t; x++)
    {
        System.out.format("%-15d%-20f%-29f%-29f\n", time.get(x), derivative.get(x), nominalInterestSum.get(x), realInterestSum.get(x));
    }
}


private XYDataset createDataset() {

    final XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("Investment Function");
    final XYSeries series2 = new XYSeries("Real Investment Function");
    final XYSeries series3 = new XYSeries("Derivative Function");

    int iteration = 0;
    double realSum = investment;
    int t = time;
    int r = rate;
    double i = investment;
    double ir = interestRate;
    double decimalInterestRate = ir/100;

    Interest temp = new Interest(i, ir, t, r);

    ArrayList<Integer> time = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Double> derivative = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> nominalInterestSum = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> realInterestSum = new ArrayList<Double>();


    for(int x = 0; x <= t; x++)
    {
        time.add(iteration);
        iteration++;
        derivative.add(temp.getDerivative(x));
        nominalInterestSum.add(i * (Math.pow(((decimalInterestRate/r) + 1), (x * r))));
        realInterestSum.add((((Math.pow(((decimalInterestRate/r) + 1), (x * r)))/((Math.pow(((inflation) + 1), (x))))) * i));
        //realInterestSum.add(i * (Math.pow((((decimalInterestRate - inflation)/r) + 1), (x * r))));
    }

    for(int x = 0; x <= t; x++)
    {
        series1.add(time.get(x), nominalInterestSum.get(x));
        series2.add(time.get(x), realInterestSum.get(x));
        series3.add(time.get(x), derivative.get(x));
    }

    XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
    dataset.addSeries(series1);
    dataset.addSeries(series2);
    dataset.addSeries(series3);

    return dataset;

}

private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {

    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Interest Investment", "Time", "Money", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);

    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

    XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

    XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
    renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(0, false);
    renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(1, false);
    renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(4));
    /*renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(0, true);
    renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(0, false);
    renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(1, false);
    renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(1, true);*/



    plot.setRenderer(renderer);

    NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
    rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());

    return chart;

}

public void displayChart(final String title) {

    final XYDataset dataset = createDataset();
    final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
    final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
    ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame(title, chart);
    frame.pack(); 
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


}
```

How exactly would I change the style and coloring of the lines being graphed. Right now, there are some default line coloring and style. Is there any way to alter this from the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How exactly would I change the style and coloring of the lines being graphed.

You can change how each series is rendered through a [XYLineAndShapeRenderer](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html) (for instance the one created in the `createChart` method). For example, to change the rendering of the first series (index 0):

```
renderer.setSeriesPaint(0,Color.CYAN);//change rendered color to cyan
renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(0, false);//no lines between points
renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(4));//the thickness of any lines being rendered
```

See the API of the link provided for more ways to customize how each series is rendered.

Comment: Thank you. That really helped me. Feel kind of stupid that I didn't notice that.